# How to set up rollup so that a Svelte project is automatically compiled on save without being served?

Tags: svelte, rollupjs

In a Svelte project there are already three scripts set up inside the `package.json` file

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c",
    "dev": "rollup -c -w",
    "start": "sirv public --single"
  },
```

What I understand from the `rollup.config.js` file

- running `npm run build` compiles the project to the `public` folder and minifies the files once
- running `npm run dev` compiles without minifying and automatically runs `npm run start` after compilation so the public folder is served and reloaded on change

Since I'm using firebase emulators which includes emulating the hosting and serving of the public directory I'm looking for a way to only automatically compile the Svelte project when saving without the serving ~ how can I achieve this?

EDIT: How can I achieve this by modifying the `rollup.config` in a way that an additional script e.g. `"autobuild": "..."` can be added to easily switch between the different modes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the `plugins` sections of a [default Rollup config file for a Svelte project](https://github.com/sveltejs/template/blob/master/rollup.config.js), Rollup conditionally performs the following 3 steps :

```js
    // In dev mode, call `npm run start` once
    // the bundle has been generated
    !production && serve(),

    // Watch the `public` directory and refresh the
    // browser on changes when not in production
    !production && livereload('public'),

    // If we're building for production (npm run build
    // instead of npm run dev), minify
    production && terser()
```

In order to prevent your site being automatically served, and your browser automatically refreshed, you can simply comment out the first 2 steps. With the watch flag (`-w`) still set, your project will still rebuild automatically upon save, provided you started it with `npm run dev`.

And if you always want your files minified, you can remove the environment condition in the third step.

So the end of your `plugins` section would look like this instead:

```js
    // In dev mode, call `npm run start` once
    // the bundle has been generated
    // !production && serve(),

    // Watch the `public` directory and refresh the
    // browser on changes when not in production
    // !production && livereload('public'),

    // If we're building for production (npm run build
    // instead of npm run dev), minify
    // production && terser()
    terser()
```

In addition, if these changes are permanent and you know you will never need to hot serve content, you can remove the `serve()` function definition near the top of the config file, as well as remove the `import` statement for `rollup-plugin-livereload` (which provides the `livereload()` function).

Comment: Thanks for this solution! I will go with the uncommenting, but since I have to switch between the modes, that's not absolutely convenient and I'm wondering if there was a way to modify the rollup.config so a script can be added to switch between the three modes `build / autobuild / dev`? I found [an article from 2019](https://dev.to/jacobherrington/setting-up-a-svelte-project-in-seconds-with-degit-4dpa) where it looks like a svelte project was once set up with these options

Comment: Probably the most straightforward way to achieve this would be to use specific config files for each option, then use that config file as an argument following the `-c` flag (which, if passed without a filename, defaults to `rollup.config.js`). So for example you could have `rollup.build.config.js`, `rollup.autobuild.config.js`, etc. files. The actual number of files required and which to use in what step depends on your end use case, really ;)

Comment: Another way to do this would be to define your own ENV variable and toggle the execution of plugin scripts accordingly. Plenty of ways to achieve the same result :) Perhaps this way is simpler & DRYer, however.

Comment: Perfect, these hints help a lot! I was already wondering about the variable, but didn't find anything on how to define one oneself... think I now found the [right section in the docs](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#--environment-values) Thanks again!