# How to develop a SvelteKit application with same origin backend?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm working on a project with a SvelteKit frontend and a go server for hosting static files (including the frontend) and APIs. Everything works fine if I ship a SvelteKit static production build with my server in the end. However, when I'm running SvelteKit in dev mode, it is starting up it's own server, which breaks my relative API paths (because of the different ports) and creates cors issues.

What is the proper way to resolve this kind of problems? Currently I'm searching for something like a SvelteKit build watch mode or a way to lunch dev mode without a custom server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set up rollup so that a Svelte project is automatically compiled on save without being served?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71205050/how-to-set-up-rollup-so-that-a-svelte-project-is-automatically-compiled-on-save)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think so. Unlike Svelte, SvelteKit seems not to come with a rollup.config.js file.

Comment: Ah right, my bad. You can probably achieve something similar with the Vite config though, this is the direction you should look.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable csrf with checkOrigin: false while in dev and re-enable on build.

https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/configuration#csrf